# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, controller

I'm following the Michael Hartl tutorial and I found a problem and don't know how solved it... my problem is around [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.0#code%3afollowing_followers_actions) whitout ajax.

when I try to do follow to other user I got this:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/follows_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

here is my "follows" controller eq to relationships

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:follows][:followed_id])
  current_user.follow!(@user)
  redirect_to @user
end

def destroy
 @user = Follow.find(params[:id]).followed
 current_user.unfollow!(@user)
 redirect_to @user
end
```

the rest (models,rspec) I have the same
if you need more code tell me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that `params[:follows]` is nil. Check what parameters you're submitting to the `create` action.

Comment: thanks I checked it out and found that I got a wrong parameter